# How standalone are packaged Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, package

I have a HTML5 app, that I need to redistribute as a desktop application. One solution could be Chrome packaged apps, but it seems you can only install those packages using the Chrome webstore.

Is there an easy way to distribute Chrome apps using a stand-alone installer, and without requiring the end-user to have Chrome installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CefView example from the [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) project could server for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can install them using the .crx file given to you while packaging, but that still requires chrome. Actually, you pretty much have to somehow have chrome on the target, as the standalone apps use it's framework. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know the standalone app has to contain the engine, but it should be an embedded/portable version, not requiring the user to actually install Chrome.